# Python loops program

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

The point of the below program so far is to obtain the nearest 1 vowel by iterating from the location of the consonant on the `alphabet` list until the end of the `alphabet` list. Ones the loop finds the nearest (to the right) vowel, the loop should stop iterating and assign the index and letter of that vowel to the `afterVowel` and `afterVowelIndex` variables. The same should be done with every consonant (that is, if the current iteration of the input (`word`) is a consonant, we put it on the `alphabet` list and then iterate though the `alphabet` list to find the nearest-to-the-right vowel, then stop).

The problem is, it iterates though the `alphabet` list and outputs *all* the vowels to the right of the consonant on the alphabet instead of only *one*.

I tried using break, while loops with conditionals, and other techniques and nothing works, unfortunately.

How can this be fixed?

PS. The `print` statement below is used to check if one or more vowels are outputted; it is not an actual part of the program.

```
def rovarspraket(word = raw_input("Please enter a word: ")):

    consonants = ['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z']
    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
    alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

    #1. Identify if the current element is a consonant, the consonant, and the consonant's index on alphabet list
    for character in range(len(word.lower())):
        for c in range(len(consonants)):
            if word[character] == consonants[c]:
                currentConsonant = word[character]

            #2. Determine After and Before vowels

                #After vowel 
                for a in range(alphabet.index(word[character]), len(alphabet)): 
                    for aV in range(len(vowels)):
                        if alphabet[a] == vowels[aV]:
                            afterVowel = alphabet[a]
                            afterVowelIndex = a
                            print afterVowel, afterVowelIndex
```

Comment: What is done about characters after 'u'? Do we consider 'a' the closest to the right? Also, what if a character in word is a vowel, do we output that value or do we output the next vowel after that? What if a use inputs a number or a symbol? Are we trusting the user will not do that?

Comment: Is this the exactly the same question as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774454/python-2-7-assignment)?

Comment: @ljetibo looks like it

Comment: wow… an exact duplicate.  what a coincidence...

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi I left most of the program out of this, as you and others have correctly pointed out, me and my partner have asked the same question 2 times on 2 different accounts and got no response because we were told to narrow down the problem. So don't worry about the 'u', it's taken care of. If the character in a word is a vowel it's skipped, and we're trusting the user will only input lowercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping I understand your question correctly. If I am, couldn't you solve this with just one boolean flag?

```
def rovarspraket(word = raw_input("Please enter a word: ")):

consonants = ['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z']
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

#1. Identify if the current element is a consonant, the consonant, and the consonant's index on alphabet list
for character in range(len(word.lower())):
    for c in range(len(consonants)):
        if word[character] == consonants[c]:
            currentConsonant = word[character]

        #2. Determine After and Before vowels

            #After vowel
            flag = False
            for a in range(alphabet.index(word[character]), len(alphabet)): 
                for aV in range(len(vowels)):
                    if alphabet[a] == vowels[aV] and not flag:
                        afterVowel = alphabet[a]
                        afterVowelIndex = a
                        print afterVowel, afterVowelIndex
                        flag = True
```

Comment: This is not an optimal solution, as it will keep iterating after it has found a vowel.

Comment: While this is true, and `break` is the better solution, he said he tried it and it didn't work (whether that be true or not), so I wanted to give a different way. But yes, OP, try to make `break` work.

Answer (score 0):

`break` will exit out of one loop. You need a flag to break out of the second:

```
done = False

for a in range(alphabet.index(word[character]), len(alphabet)): 
    for aV in range(len(vowels)):
        if alphabet[a] == vowels[aV]:
            afterVowel = alphabet[a]
            afterVowelIndex = a
            print afterVowel, afterVowelIndex
            done = True
            break

    if done:
        break
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you did with the "flagging"? I'm new to programming, and haven't dealt with breaking nested loops before. Did you break the second loop by using break and then broke out of the first loop using if done: break?